# sql update query didn't execute but return no errror

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

```
$id = 1; //temp

$promoTitle = trim($_POST['promoTitle']);
$imageURL = trim($_POST['imageURL']);
$affLink = trim($_POST['affLink']);
$couponCode = trim($_POST['couponCode']);

$stmt = $db->prepare('UPDATE dashboard SET promoTitle=?, image=?, url=?, couponCode=? WHERE id=?');

$q = $stmt->bind_param('ssssi', $promoTitle, $imageURL, $affLink, $couponCode, $id);

if($result = $db->query($q)){
    echo "updated";
}else{
    echo mysql_errno();
}
```

stuck for half an hour and still couldn't find out what's wrong. I has return no error. My table look like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/7I1xh.png

Comment: The third step of prepare, bind, execute is `$stmt->execute()`, not `$db->query()`.

Comment: This should explode as `query()` wants a query string, not a prepared statement. If you're not getting errors, you may need to adjust your PHP configuration so you can find/see them.

Comment: you are using pdo object, instead of query() use execute()

Comment: also put your code inside try catch to  get actual exception.

Answer (score -1):

you can use this for updation in mysql from php

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    try{
        $id = 1; //temp

        $promoTitle = trim($_POST['promoTitle']);
        $imageURL = trim($_POST['imageURL']);
        $affLink = trim($_POST['affLink']);
        $couponCode = trim($_POST['couponCode']);

        $stmt = $db->prepare('UPDATE  dashboard  SET promoTitle = :promoTitle, image = :image, url  = :url, couponCode=:couponCode WHERE id =:id');
        $stmt->execute(array(
          ':promoTitle' => $promoTitle,
          ':image' => $image,
          ':url' => $url,
          ':couponCode' => $couponCode,             
          ':id' =>$id                        
        ));

    //redirect to Your page page
   header('Location: page.php?action=updated');
   exit;
  }

  catch(PDOException $e) {
      echo $e->getMessage();
  }

}
```

Comment: That's PDO, but OP is using mysqli.